# Socket send with MSG_WAITALL got 22 EINVAL

Tags: c++, sockets, posix

```
bool AbstractSocket::send(void *data, const size_t &size)
{
    ssize_t result = ::send(m_sfd, data, size, MSG_WAITALL);
    if (result == -1 ) {
        if (errno != EAGAIN) {
            LOG_ERR("failed to write socket")
            emitErrorSignal();
        } else { // else If errno == EAGAIN
            // that means we have read all data.
            return true;
        }
    } else if (result == 0) {
        // The remote has closed the connection
        LOG_WNG("the remote has closed the connection")
        emitErrorSignal(std::errc::connection_aborted);
    }
    return size == static_cast<size_t>(result);
}
```

I am trying to create a send function with specified size which sends all the data.
Why `send` raise `EINVAL` error? What argument is invalid?

Comment: Could be any argument. Unfortunately, a [mre] is required here, and posting a link to some external web site is not sufficient to meet the requirements for a [mre].

Comment: `send()` doesn't support the MSG_WAITALL flag. It would be redundant in blocking mode, as that's how it already behaves, and meaningless in non-blocking mode, which is required, err, not to block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What argument is invalid?

`send` function does not have the `MSG_WAITALL` option. So `MSG_WAITALL` is invalid.

`send` only support:

- MSG_EOR
- MSG_OOB

https://linux.die.net/man/3/send